# Firebase database WEB get data in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It is possible to get data from Firebase database from Javascript (WEB) directly in JSON  format ?

Currently I'm using this function and I must to parse all data and convert it to JSON array

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/').once('value', function(snap){
        snap.forEach(function(obj){
            console.log(obj.val());
            // Parsing obj and saving to JSON array ...
        })
    })
```

It would be nice if I can get data directly in JSON format (like in Firebase console).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if you just `JSON.stringify()` it? Does that get you what you're looking for?

```
firebase.database().ref('posts/').once('value', function(snap){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(snap.val()))
})
```

Comment: You're right ! It was really stupid question. Thank you !